# Need help converting $z = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$ to polar

Tags: polar-coordinates

The full question is this:

Volume of a solid in any region R is given by: $$\int\!\!\!\int_Rf(x,y)dydx $$

where, $$f(x,y) = z = \ln(x^2+y^2)$$

and, $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

There for, $$dydx = \_\_\_drd\theta$$

My answer is:
  $$r\ln(r^2)\, dr\,d\theta$$

but the book says the correct answer is:
$$r \,dr\,d\theta$$

How is that so?

Comment: Chain Rule is what you missed.

Answer (score 2):

There two different things:
$\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is transformed into $\ln(r^2)$, **and** $dx\,dy$ is transformed into $r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Of course I cannot know, what exactly states yor book, but at least partially it tells the truth.

Comment: I updated the full text from the book, I am still not getting the book answer.

Comment: I searched for this theorem on the internet and I couldn't find it, so I wonder if you can please tell me if it is true or not, and send me a link to check it up if possible, and thanks in advance. The theorem is if $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\alpha}f(x) =0$ and $\alpha >1$ then, $\int _0^1f(x) dx$ is convergent. Also another question please, how can we use this theorem for proving that $\int_0^R r.\ln r dr$ is convergent?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, I was dumb.

I real realized the question was asking what $dxdy = r drd\theta$

It didn't ask me to convert $ln(x^2+y^2)dxdy to drd\theta$

Comment: :-) So your book tells the truth.